# Trigger.io native plugins and source control

Tags: android, iphone, trigger.io

So, I'm using Trigger.io to create some native plugins for iOS and Android.

The Toolkit will automatically create the inspector projects for you.

My question is - are these projects are likely to change in between major (/minor) updates to trigger.io? Are there certain files that we should try *not* to place into source control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do sometimes update the inspector projects in minor platform version releases - most of the time, those changes won't affect your development: bug fixes, improvements to unrelated modules and so on. For those cases, just changing the `platform_version` in `manifest.json` and updating your inspector projects will pick up the new code.

However, in some cases we also change the HTML/CSS/JS the runnable inspector apps use (e.g. support for [working with files](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/file_objects.html)). In those cases, you need to remove your existing inspector projects from your file system before updating, so that you get a clean start with the new inspector app.

**Note**, however, that this will delete any manual changes you made to the inspector app in `assets/src` - you'll need to re-do those changes after updating.

The main update to the inspector projects that we have planned will fix this slightly awkward workflow - even platform versions that affect the inspector apps will be seamlessly updateable by just changing your manifest: that change is probably 1 - 2 months out.

At the moment, my recommendation would be to put all of the plugin files into version control (e.g. https://github.com/trigger-corp/plugin-multi-image-select).